# How to render Views anchors with `title` attribute?

Tags: 7, views, entities

By default the Views module doesn't put `title` attributes on anchors as it only puts them on anything that has an `alt` attribute.

Seeing as you're not likely to have an `alt` attribute on a standard anchor. Could someone please advise what you need to do in order to render Views anchors with `title` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can supply your own 'alt' attribute (and thus 'title' when rendered) by outputting your field as a link. Choose "Output this field as a link", and enter the path, and alt text from the available tokens. Sometimes you might have to define a separate 'path' field for use in the 'link path' value. You might also have to experiment with the "Use absolute path" setting to get the href right.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

In your `Content: Title` expand `Rewrite Results` and check `Rewrite the output of this field`

In the Text field enter: `<a id="[title]">[title]</a>`
This will create your anchor jump point.

Next you can add a block and repeat the same process replacing Text field with `<a href="#[title]">[title]</a>`